# Binding, borrowing method

Tags: javascript, arrays, bind

Could you explain the difference:

```
var obj = {
  0: "A",
  1: "B",
  2: "C",
  length: 3,
  print: function(){ console.log(this) }
};

//A (borrowing method. No changes in obj): 
[].join.call(obj, "+"); //-> "A+B+C"

//B:
obj.join = [].join.bind(obj); 
obj.join("+"); //-> "A+B+C"
var oj = obj.join;
oj("-"); //-> "A-B-C" (binded to obj)

//C:
obj.j = [].join;
obj.j("++"); //-> "A+B+C"
var j = obj.j;
j("-"); //-> "A-B-C" (it still binded!)

//D:
var join = [].join.bind(obj)
join("+"); //-> "A+B+C"

//E (not working: [] is a new array every time):
[].join.bind(obj);
[].join("+"); //expected: "A+B+C" but I have: ""

//F (Danger!)
Array.prototype.join = [].join.bind(obj);
[].join("+"); //"A+B+C"
```

Could you explain is there difference between A and B?
What's the difference between B and C?
Why E doesn't work?

(Extra question) Could you explain how to unbind method after F?

```
Array.prototype.join = [].join.bind(null);
[].join([1,2,3,4],"+"); //-> "ABC"
```

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Well, E doesn't work because `[].join.bind(obj)` and `[].join("+")` are two completely separate arrays. And the difference between A and B are that in A you are actually invoking the function with `call` and in B you are returning the function with a bound `this` context and setting the object's join function to the newly bound function.

Comment: You're asking several questions.

Comment: Yes. correct: [].join.bind(obj) and [].join("+") are two completely separate arrays. Thank you mhodges for comment. What the difference between B and C?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Is there a difference between A and B

Yes, A does not modify `obj` as mentioned in the comment.

2) Is there a difference between B and C

Other than the fact that one will print 'A++B++C', yes. B is explicitly bound, whereas C is not which means it can lose context. Try the following:

```
var fn = obj.join
var fn2 = obj.j

console.log(fn('+')) // works
console.log(fn2('+')) // error
```

3) Why is E not working?

```
[].join.bind(obj);
// ^ this is an array instance
// calling `join.bind(obj)` makes no modification to that array instance or any other
[].join("+"); //expected: "A+B+C" but I have: ""
// ^ this is different array instance, unaffected by the above call
```

4) Could you explain how to unbind method after F?

You cannot unbind a bound function that is bound using javascript's native `bind` method. You can write your own version which is unbindable, but this is not part of the native API.

Here is a trivial implementation:

```
function bind(fn, context) {
  var newFn = function () { return fn.call(context, arguments) }
  newFn.unbind = function () { return fn }
  return newFn
}

function checkCtx (a) { console.log(this, a) }
checkCtx(1); // Window, 1
bind(checkCtx, {})(1) // {}, 1
bind(checkCtx, {}).unbind()(1) // Window, 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution how to unbind method:
`**You cannot unbind** a bound function that is bound using javascript's native bind method.`